# Using Regex to find string that contains one string and excludes a second string?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to come up with a single regex expression that matches all strings that contain "mobile" and do not contain "video" I've been struggling to do this in a single expression and would appreciate any help.

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: I'm trying to do this in bash

Answer (score 4):

Use the negative look-ahead assertion:

```
^(?!.*video).*mobile
```

Example:

```
$ cat 1.txt
audio-mobile
mobile-video
mobile-video
video-mobile
videomobile
mobile
audio-mobile
audio

$ grep -P '^(?!.*video).*mobile' 1.txt
audio-mobile
mobile
audio-mobile
```