# Improve JS Regex to exclude lines that contain a certain string

Tags: regex

I have a JS regex to replace sections of a string that include img tags inside p tags. I'm picking up ones I don't want.

Sample of what I want to find and replace (the src and class are not always in the same order and imageData is not always the same base64 "numbers", so I can't just match on the whole string):

```
<p><img class="classIWantToMatch" src="data:image/gif;base64,dataForImage"></p>
<p><img src="data:image/gif;base64,imageData" class="classIWantToMatch" ></p>
```

Sample that is also getting found and replaced (but I don't want to):

```
<p><img src="/myFiles/my.PNG" alt=""></p>
```

Regex:

```
/(<p><img).*?(class="classIWantToMatch").*?(<\/p>)/g
```

I'm trying to figure out lookahead and lookbehind, but I can't seem to make it do what I want.

Besides ye olde basic googling, I tried here:

[A Regex that search for lines that contains a string, and not contains another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856996/a-regex-that-search-for-lines-that-contains-a-string-and-not-contains-another-s)

[Using Regex to find string that contains one string and excludes a second string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867466/using-regex-to-find-string-that-contains-one-string-and-excludes-a-second-string)

and several other ones as well. I think I just don't understand lookahead/behind.

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/kWdUS3/1) might help you to only get your desired target or design an expression to do so:

```
(<p><img.+class=\")(classIWantToMatch)(\".+<\/p>)
```

[image]

- You can only bound your desired target in second capturing group.
- With a simple left boundary as `(<p><img.+class=\")` and right boundary as `(\".+<\/p>)` you might be able to do so. However, you might consider making these boundaries more restrictive just to be safe. For instance, `.+` can be much limited to a list of chars.

Comment: I'm trying this out in regex101, but it barrels right past the closing p tag and ends up encompassing subsequent p tags. How can I stop it at the first p tag that follows (at some varying interval) the classIWantToMatch?

Comment: <p><img src="data:image/gif;base64,imageDate" class="mce-pagebreak" data-mce-resize="false" data-mce-placeholder=""></p><p><strong>Some text</strong></p><p><img src="/myFiles/my.PNG" alt="" data-mce-src="/myFiles/my.PNG"><img src="/myFiles/my.PNG" alt="" width="918" height="404" data-mce-src="/myFiles/my.PNG"></p><ul><li>Entrances increased 6% from 5,681 to 6,009</li><ul><li><strong>Some text</strong></li></ul><p>Some Text</p><p><img src="data:image/gif;base64,imageData" class="mce-pagebreak" data-mce-resize="false" data-mce-placeholder=""></p><p>Some Text</p>

Comment: The above is a sample of code that is "failing" in regex101, it goes all the way to the last closing p tag it can find.

Comment: The p tag (containing the img tag) that I need to replace will always have that class, mce-pagebreak. I suppose it could have others, but it WILL have that one.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for helping!